# UIButton is not updating programmatically until the second click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

So I have a UITableCell that contains a button to add a specific friend on my app.  When the friend request submits to the database on my app, I want the button text to change from "Add" to "Added".  However, with my current code, the title does not change until I click the button the second time, even though it reaches the same part of the code, the button will not change unless I click it a second time (And I want to eventually disable this button once it changes the text).

Here is my code:

```
[[dynamoDBMapper save:friend] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                    if (task.error) {
                        NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
                    }
                    if (task.exception) {
                        NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
                    }
                    if (task.result) {
                        NSLog(@"Task result is %@", task.result);
                        NSLog(@"You've made it to the change text section");
                         [_addBtn setTitle:@"Added" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }


                    return nil;
                }];
```

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?  Or is there another way that I can change the button text for `_addBtn`?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the _addBtn setTitle: line and check two things: _addBtn is not nil, and you are on the main thread. If either of those is false, the UI update will fail.

Comment: Is that block asynchronous? Try to update the button's title on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an asynchronous issue. Create a method like

```
- (void)updateButton
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   
        // update button title
        // disable button
   });
}
```

And call this method from inside `if (task.result) { }`

Comment: If it was an asynchronous issue, wouldn't the console have printed something along the lines of "you are attempting to modify UI from background thread"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure if that block is executed in main thread then you can check it by using this method: `[NSThread isMainThread]`. That way, you will know the flow of your program. If it is not in the main thread, then you cannot update **ANY** UI element. All changes regarding UI **MUST** be done in the main thread. I just changed your code to give you a sample.

```
[[dynamoDBMapper save:friend] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)
{
    if (task.error)
    {
        NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
    }

    if (task.exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
    }

    if (task.result)
    {
        NSLog(@"Task result is %@", task.result);
        NSLog(@"You've made it to the change text section");

        //check if current block is in main thread.
        if([NSThread isMainThread])
        {
            NSLog(@"The block is in main thread");

            [_addBtn setTitle:@"Added" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"The block is not in main thread");

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
            {
               [_addBtn setTitle:@"Added" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            });
        }
    }

    return nil;
}];
```